How can I transform a petl table across all CPUs?
I created an ETL pipeline using Python ETL PETL.
It works as expected, but my current transformation part is a bit slow.
I'm utilizing ProcessPoolExecutor to transform each petl data table in separate process. I realized that perhaps working on 1 data table at a time across all CPUs might be more performant than trying to work all data tables across CPUs since we might not be able to use all CPUs when there is a less number of work to be done than the number of cores.
I guess my question is:

does this thought process make sense?
Is there a way to work on a single transformation work across all cores and join the results back?

What I have, simplified:
def transform(data_tables):
  results = {}
  futures = {}

  with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for table in data_tables.items():
      futures[executor.submit(transform_table, table)]

    for future in as_completed(futures):
      try:
        results[name] = future.result()
      except Exception as exc:
      # handling exception...

  return results


